# NSFetchedResultsController: delete 1 row crashes the app

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Deleting a row from a UITableView fed by an NSFetchedResultsController causes my app to crash.

Error is:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:1330
>
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I want only swipe-to-delete. My deletion code goes like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];  
    SequenceData *sd = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];  
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:sd];  
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];  
    [self.tableView endUpdates];  
}
```

My NSFetchedResultsController is set up just like in Ray Wanderlich's tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Number of rows is determined by:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {    
    id sectionObjects = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];  
    NSInteger nbObjects = [sectionObjects numberOfObjects];  
    return nbObjects;  
}
```

It looks like the fetch is not updating (number of rows does not vary). Do I need to fetch myself (isn't this taking care of by the fetch controller)?

There is obviously something basic I am missing here. Don't hesitate to suggest basic answers.

I first implemented this with the controller: didChangeObject: ... method. Error was the same, but some details differed.

**Edit**
I believe my problem is fixed. Both answers (From CX and Martin) helped me find it. Martin got the answer because of the explanations that helped me understand a little bit better...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't call

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

if you use a fetched results controller. Only delete the object with

```
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:sd];
```

The fetched results controller *delegate method* `didChangeObject:` is then called automatically,
and that calls `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`.

So in your case, the row was deleted twice, and that caused the exception.

Note that you don't need `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` here.

Comment: Thank you. Implementing your answer doesn't crash the app anymore, but the row is not deleted from the table view. The data is deleted, though. Do I need any kind of implementation of didChangeObject?

Comment: @invalidArgument: Yes, you have to implement the 4 fetched results controller delegate methods. Have a look at *"Ok one more thing – we need to implement the delegate methods for the NSFetchedResultsController"* and the following code in the tutorial. - It is also documented in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html.

Comment: Implementing those methods makes my app crash again. So within `commitEditingStyle`, I am only deleting the object. Within `didChangeObject`, it's copy-paste from the tutorial (and so having `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` there). Exception is actually thrown on that line, with both indexPath and newIndexPath nil. (I also added `controllerWillChanteContent` and `controllerDidChangeContent`)

Comment: @invalidArgument: That is strange, `indexPath` should not be nil in the NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete case.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete a row you need to delete managedObject only.

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Deleting the managed object triggers the `NSFetchResultController`  delegate methods, and they will update the `tableView`.

**Edit**

You should implement NSFetchResultController delegate method

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{
switch(type) {
 case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
}


////
   default:
   break;
    }
```

Because when you work with data source like NSFetchedResultsController, all changes must come from there and your table only reflects them.

Comment: Thank you. My answer to your suggestion will be similar to the one I gave to Martin. Data gets deleted, but rows don't disappear. What should I look for?

Comment: are you implementing NSFetchResultController's delegates...?

Comment: Yes I am. `controllerWillChangeContent`, `controller: didChangeObject: ...` and `controllerDidChangeContent`

Comment: Have you update code with my latest edit, are you calling `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` inside didChange or willChange, you should add this in one better will you are adding didChange ....

Comment: `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` is implemented in `controller: didChangeObject:` in the `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` case. Inside `willChange` and `didChange` I do `[self.tableView beginUpdates]` and `[self.tableView endUpdates]`, respectively.

Comment: It should work then, but we can test, do one thing replace this code with [tableView reloadData]; and see what happen...

Comment: With `[tableview reloadData]` inside of `controller: didChangeObject:`, I get this error:  `An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be == to the # of rows contained in that section before the update (1), +/- the # of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and +/- the # of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)`