# Error when deleting row from UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm having an error when trying to delete from UITableView. My TableView is from CoreData. Here is my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        context.delete(mealCore[indexPath.row])
        appDelegate.saveContext()
        print("context saved")
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

my context is getting saved. But when it tries to delete it from the tableview, it crashes with the following errror:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Would really appreciate any advice.  Thanks!!!

Just adding the some codes that might help? I might be doing something wrong:
    var mealCore = NSManagedObject
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat="dd/mm/yyyy"


    let mealRec = mealCore[indexPath.row]

    cell.mealName!.text = mealRec.value(forKey: "meal") as? String

    if let dateHolder = mealRec.value(forKey: "mealdate"){

       cell.mealDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: dateHolder as! Date)
    }
    if let data = mealRec.value(forKey: "mealimage")as? NSData {
        cell.mealImage?.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
    }

    return cell

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"FoodLog")

    do {
        let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        mealCore = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return mealCore.count
}
```

Comment: Are you using an NSFetchedResultsController as table view data source? Compare [NSFetchedResultsController: delete 1 row crashes the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222840/nsfetchedresultscontroller-delete-1-row-crashes-the-app).

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm using   NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>

Comment: Show your "number of rows in section" and "cell for row at index path" methods.

Comment: Hi Martin,  Thanks for helping me on this. I have added the codes in the original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to delete object from `mealCore` array.

**Swift 3**

```
mealCore.remove(atIndex: indexPath.row)
```

**Swift 4**

```
mealCore.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

Comment: awesome!! it worked!! thanks trick14!! i would also like thank all the guys here for all their suggestions! you guys rock!!

Answer (score -1):

Try making a call to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` like so:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: What difference should that make for a single update?

Comment: Always seems to solve the problem for me, but yes I agree it is as much a mystery to me as it is you.